# Set value for a Sitecore Name Value Field using PowerShell

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

I have a `Name Value List` field in Sitecore called "PageSchema". I need to add another name, and value to this PageSchema field using PowerShell.

How can I do it from PowerShell? What I want is something like this.

```
{
        $ArticleItem.Editing.BeginEdit()
        try {
             NameValueCollection data = new NameValueCollection()
             data.Add("name", "value")
             ArticleItem["PageSchema"] = StringUtil.NameValuesToString(data, "&")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example taken from the [official docs](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/code-snippets/field-types#edit-namevaluelistfield).

**Example:** The following example gets all of the name/value pairs of a NameValueListField and appends a new pair.

```
$item = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{371EEE15-B6F3-423A-BB25-0B5CED860EEA}"

$nameValues = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString($item.UrlMapping)

# Here you can add or remove name/value pairs
$nameValues["^/ab[cde]/$"] = "/somewhere/fun?lang=en"

foreach($key in $nameValues.AllKeys) {
    $nameValues[$key] = [Uri]::EscapeDataString($nameValues[$key])
}

$item.UrlMapping = [Sitecore.StringUtil]::NameValuesToString($nameValues,"&")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below script to update your `PageSchema` field value for the `Name Value List` field.

```
$item = Get-Item -Path "master:\content\home"

$nameValues = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString($item.PageSchema)

$nameValues["Key3"] = "Value3"

Write-Host "Result before update $($item.PageSchema)"

$item.PageSchema = [Sitecore.StringUtil]::NameValuesToString($nameValues,"&")

Write-Host "Result after update $($item.PageSchema)"
```

In this case, I tried on the home item, Refer to the following screenshot for more clarity.

**1. Have 2 key value items initially on the Home item.**

[image]

**2. Result of executing the above script.**

[image]

**3. Updated values of `Name Value List` field.**

[image]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use two ways to do it.

**Option 1:**

As per the [Sitecore Official Document](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/code-snippets/field-types#edit-namevaluelistfield), If you want to add a new `key-Value` in the `Name Value List` field. Here is the code that you can use.

```
# Get your Item
$item = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{1CE0717B-0225-48A1-A857-50A59EE1BF85}"

$nameValues = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString($item.Schema)

# Here you can add name/value pair
$nameValues["Key4"] = "Value4"

$item.Schema = [Sitecore.StringUtil]::NameValuesToString($nameValues,"&")
```

**Option2:**

If you will see the raw value of the field, the format looks like this.

```
Key1=Value1&Key2=Value2&Key3=Value3
```

So you can add a new key on the item edit by using below code.

```
$item = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{1CE0717B-0225-48A1-A857-50A59EE1BF85}"
#$item.Editing.BeginEdit()
#$item.Fields["Schema"].Value = $item.Fields["Schema"].Value + "&" + "Key3=Value3"
#$item.Editing.EndEdit()
```

In both of the cases, the value will be added to your field like below.

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one if you want for bulk item.

[image]